# Why won't BufferedWriter write from client to server?

Tags: java, sockets, client, server

I am building a client-server application using threading, but for some reason the `BufferedWriter` won't send the data out to the client through the socket.
I also get a `Socket Exception: Connection Reset` after running the client.
What am i missing?
Server:

```
public class Servernew {

protected String username;

protected ServerSocket serverSocket;

protected static LinkedList<ClientThreadNew> clients;

public static LinkedList<ClientThreadNew> getClients() {
    return clients;
}

public Servernew(int port) {
    try {

        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

        clients = new LinkedList<ClientThreadNew>();
        System.out.println("Server is now running on port " + port);

        while (true) {

            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

            ClientThreadNew clientThread = new ClientThreadNew(
                    clientSocket, username);

            clients.addLast(clientThread);

            clientThread.start();



        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) { 

    new Servernew(4444);
}
```

}

ClientThread:

```
public class ClientThreadNew extends Thread implements Runnable {

protected String username;

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

protected Socket clientSocket;

protected BufferedReader inFromClientB;




protected BufferedWriter outToClient;




public ClientThreadNew(Socket clientSocket, String username)
        throws IOException {

    this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    this.username = username;



    inFromClientB = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            clientSocket.getInputStream()));



    outToClient = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));

}

public void run() {


    try {

        while (true) {



            String incomingMessage = inFromClientB.readLine();

            if (incomingMessage != null) {


                setUsername(incomingMessage);


                outToClient.write("hii");
                outToClient.newLine();
                outToClient.flush();




            }

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.print(e);

    }

}
```

}

ClientTest:

```
public class ClientTesst {
private static Socket socket;
private static BufferedWriter outToServer;
private String hostname;
private int portnum;
private static BufferedReader inFromServer;

public ClientTesst(String hostname, int portnum) throws IOException {
    this.hostname = hostname;
    this.portnum = portnum;

}

public void connect() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {

    socket = new Socket(hostname, portnum);
    System.out.println("Connection Established");
}

public String listUsers() throws IOException {

    inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            socket.getInputStream()));
    String listOfUsers = inFromServer.readLine().toString();

    return (listOfUsers);
}

public void sendMessage(String Msg) throws IOException {



    outToServer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
            socket.getOutputStream()));
    outToServer.write(Msg);
    outToServer.newLine();
    outToServer.flush();

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ClientTesst x = new ClientTesst("localhost", 4444);
    x.connect();
    x.sendMessage("client x");

    ClientTesst y = new ClientTesst("localhost", 4444);
    y.connect();
    y.sendMessage("client y");
    y.listUsers();



}
```

}

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @radimpe I get a 'Socket Exception: Connection Reset"

Comment: Consider adding your error log to the question (by editing it) and you are likely to get some feedback. Make sure to add as much of the stacktrace as is necessary to identify the error.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but just to point you to another solution, I wrote DataFetcher back in the day when I was messing around with sockets and InputStreams: http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/io/ DataFetcher works using callbacks, so you hook the DataFetcher up to an InputStream and register one or more DataListeners. It is built to work synchronously or asynchronously

Answer (score 0):

In your `ClientTesst` class you have this:

```
private static Socket socket;
private static BufferedReader inFromServer;
private static BufferedWriter outToServer;
```

and since all this variables are `static` it means that both clients `x` and `y` will use the same `socket`, `outToServer` and `inFromServer`.

Make this variables as instance variables (by remove the `static`) so that each instance of `ClientTesst` will have its on socket and streams.

Comment: I changed them to `private Socket socket` , `private BufferedReader inFromServer` and the same for the BufferedWriter but it still isnt working..

Comment: only the socket exception i mentioned in the post. I tried to change the `BufferedWriter` all together and replace it with `PrintWriter`, still no response back to the client..

Comment: @batteredwings are you sure there is no response from the server ? You should print the returned value from the `listUsers()` method, eg: `System.out.println(y.listUsers())`. Also, in your code you're only reading the response that client `y` gets and in your server code the client sockets are never closed.

Answer (score 0):

The following works -

```
    class ClientThreadNew extends Thread implements Runnable {   

        protected String username;
        protected Socket clientSocket;
        protected BufferedReader inFromClientB;
        protected BufferedWriter outToClient;

        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }

        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }

        public ClientThreadNew(Socket clientSocket, String username) throws IOException {
            this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
            this.username = username;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                outToClient = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
                inFromClientB = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                String incomingMessage, outgoingMessage;
                while ((incomingMessage = inFromClientB.readLine()) != null) {
                    setUsername(incomingMessage);
                    System.out.println("From client: " + incomingMessage);
                    outgoingMessage = "hii";
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    outToClient.write(outgoingMessage);
                    outToClient.newLine();
                    outToClient.flush();
                    System.out.println("From server: " + outgoingMessage);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

public class ClientTest {
    private Socket socket;
    private BufferedReader inFromServer;
    private BufferedWriter outToServer;
    private String hostname;
    private int portnum;

    public ClientTest(String hostname, int portnum) throws IOException {
        this.hostname = hostname;
        this.portnum = portnum;
    }    

    public void connect() throws IOException {
        socket = new Socket(hostname, portnum);
        outToServer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
        inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println("Connection Established");
    }

    public String listUsers() throws IOException {
        return inFromServer.readLine();
    }

    public void sendMessage(String Msg) throws IOException {
        outToServer.write(Msg);
        outToServer.newLine();
        outToServer.flush();
    }    

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ClientTest x = new ClientTest("localhost", 4444);
        x.connect();
        x.sendMessage("client x");
        String messageFromServer;
        while ((messageFromServer = x.listUsers()) != null) {
            System.out.println("From server: " + messageFromServer);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            x.sendMessage("client x");
            System.out.println("From client: client x");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that still didnt solve the problem that the client doesnt receive what the server is sending from the outToClient, which is the message "hi" in this case.

Comment: @batteredwings, i only solved the socket reset issue but as you now asked about client not receiving the data from server i have fixed the other  issues. Please see the updated code above. Hope that helps.

Comment: The `BufferedWriter` is finally working! but the client and server are sending message continuously. did this happen with you when you tried it?

Comment: Yes, because this is just a test program where client is sending a message after every 2 secs and server is responding to every message of client. If you want to change that behavior you can change the program as per your use case.